# Animation in cell stopping when other cell's animation finishes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm having an issue with the animations in my `TableViewCells`. Whenever someone crosses of an item on their list, a progress bar animates from 0.0 to 1.0 in 4 seconds:

```
func startAnimation() {
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
        generator.impactOccurred()
        
        if items![indexRow!].checked {
            self.delegate?.changeButton(state: false, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID!)
            self.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
            self.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkBoxOUTLINE "), for: .normal)
        } else {

            self.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkBoxFILLED "), for: .normal)
            self.tempState = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations: {
                self.progressBar.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
          }) { (finished: Bool) in
            
                self.workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                    self.delegate?.changeButton(state: true, indexSection: self.indexSection!, indexRow: self.indexRow!, itemID: self.itemID)
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.3, execute: self.workItem!)
            
            
            }
        }
    }
```

This works, and the animation performs nicely. However, whenever multiple items are being checked quickly after each other, the animation stops when the first animation triggered is completed. [Here is a screenrecord of the issue.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/broe3gqzgjx1ka1/Screen%20Recording%202020-09-04%20at%2018.02.02.mov?dl=0)

As you can see, there are 2 major issues:

1. The animation of the other cells stop abruptly
2. Cells that aren't supposed to be deleted get deleted.

I suspect that the issues lies in the delegate method that gets triggered, and not the animation here. This is my delegate method (which updates data in Firestore):

```
func changeButton(state: Bool, indexSection: Int?, indexRow: Int?, itemID: String?) {
    if let indexSection = indexSection, let indexRow = indexRow {
        sections[indexSection].items[indexRow].checked = state
    }
    
    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()
    
    if let itemID = itemID {
        let itemRef = db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("\(indexSection!)").collection(K.FStore.items).document(itemID)
        
        if sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].checked {
            itemRef.updateData([
                K.Item.isChecked: true,
                K.Item.checkedBy: currentUserID!,
                K.Item.dateChecked: Date()
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
                if let indexSection = indexSection, let indexRow = indexRow {
                    if self.sections[indexSection].items != nil {
                        let item = self.sections[indexSection].items[indexRow]
                        
                        let itemRef = self.db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(self.currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("\(indexSection)").collection(K.FStore.items).document(item.itemID!)
                        
                        itemRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                            if let document = document, document.exists {
                                
                                
                                // Get the properties of the item
                                let name = document.data()?[K.Item.name] as? String
                                let uid = document.data()?[K.Item.uid] as? String
                                let category = document.data()?[K.Item.categoryNumber] as? Int
                                let isChecked = document.data()?[K.Item.isChecked] as? Bool
                                let dateCreated = document.data()?[K.Item.date] as? Date
                                let dateChecked = document.data()?[K.Item.dateChecked] as? Date
                                let checkedBy = document.data()?[K.Item.checkedBy] as? String
                                
                                self.db.collection(K.lists).document(self.currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sectionsChecked).document("\(category!)").collection(K.FStore.items).addDocument(data: [
                                    K.Item.name: name,
                                    K.Item.isChecked: isChecked,
                                    K.Item.categoryNumber: category,
                                    K.Item.date: dateCreated,
                                    K.Item.dateChecked: dateChecked,
                                    K.Item.checkedBy: checkedBy,
                                    K.Item.uid: uid,
                                    K.Item.dateDeleted: Date()
                                ]) { err in
                                    if let err = err {
                                        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                                    } else {
                                       let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: indexRow, section: indexSection)) as? TaskCell
                                        
                                        if let cell = cell {
                                            cell.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
                                        }
                                        
                                        // If successful, delete the item in the normal collection
                                        itemRef.delete() { err in
                                            if let err = err {
                                                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                                            } else {
                                                print("Document successfully removed!")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            itemRef.updateData([
                K.Item.isChecked : false
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does it have to do with the refreshing of the cell? I'm quite lost at this point and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone could help me out that'd be absolutely great.